# Custom Binding Initialisation with backwards compatible to source of truth

Tags: swiftui

I am initializing my Binding value in my custom way, which is working just fine, Now I like to make this custom initialisation be able to effect the source of truth, how I could possibly make this happen? For giving you more information about what I just said: my BindingView controls the incoming value right in the front door and decide the action with some logic, while this happening my Binding value became in some way unable/forgot to update source of truth, after Initialisation BindingView, ContentView and BindingView have deferent prospective of value! the goal is putting some kind of codes in initializing BindingView to make this happen, to having same value for both Views. thanks for reading and helping.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var value: Int = Int()

    var body: some View {

        Text("value of ContentView:" + value.description)
            .padding()

        Button ("update value to 0") {
            
            value = 0
        }
        .padding()

        Button ("update value to 1") {
            
            value = 1
        }
        .padding()

        BindingView(value: $value)
            .padding()
        
    }
    
}



struct BindingView: View {

    @Binding var value: Int

    init(value: Binding<Int>) {

        print("initializing Binding,", "incoming value:", value.wrappedValue.description)

        if value.wrappedValue == 0 {
            
            _value = .constant(100)
 
        }
        else {
            
            _value = value
            
        }
        
        
    }

    var body: some View {

        Text("value of BindingView:" + value.description)

    }
    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do any view modifications like that in the init. Views are constantly being re-initialized, and you shouldn't use it as a lifecycle event. Instead, update the binding value in `.onAppear`

Answer (score 0):

(1) You're setting up the binding the wrong way. The @State is the source of truth. Any child view Bindings should be vanilla `@Binding var whatever: Int`.

(2) If you want the child view to present the binding's data in a special way, then you can simply pass the wrappedValue from the parent view to the child. The child can have a computed String variable that process the Int. But processing data is an odd thing for a view to do. Better to pass that into the child view's view model. That can be a simple struct. There you just take a normal Int, no binding, and process into the string you want.

(3) If you want to validate data so that 100 turns into 0, you may want to use a view model with a property `@Published private(set) var value: Int = 0` and a `func setValue(_ new: Int)` that allows you to process the value before setting the published property. None of your views really should be handling how to model data.

(4) If you want a binding to bridge a SwiftUI control's requirement for accepting a binding (e.g., a TextField), how you want to validate data, and how you want to present your model's state, you can make a custom binding in your view model. You don't seem to be in this situation, so you can ignore this.

But, here is an example of a custom binding, located in an ObservableObject view model, that a TabView reads and updates. You can put whatever validation logic you want in set, in this case it's just mapping the new selection to an action for a redux-style store.

```swift
lazy var mode = Binding<ContrastMode> {
        self.root.state.palettes.colorPickerContrast
    } set: { newMode in
        self.root.dispatch(.palette(.setColorPickerContrastMode(newMode)))
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I know that normally I or we should not use initializing method for Views and better we is using ObservableObject in form of StateObject or EnvironmentObject, I was trying to find out which part of my code make a violation in State-Binding Kingdom, I was curious how could I fix the State-Binding problem in my code

Comment: The child init, as @NewDev pointed out. Delete it. :) You don't even need a binding, as your child view isn't changing the value. Just ask for a String and let the parent provide the State object's value. Finally, a little tip, using .description is not advised as that format can change anytime. It's just for debugging. You can do String(Int) to convert an int into a string.

Comment: you know what is the problem? I am not interested at all to play with Binding and initialization, but the BindingView has other Properties which they need to get initialized, there fore I must put Binding inside of init(), xcode wouldn't let me without Binding! that is why